# Is there a "python_sitelib" macro in setuptools?

Tags: python, rpm, setuptools, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Problem:

I need to install a python module in one my site-packages.
The site-package is coming from another RPM and I can't change that code to include my stuff.
So I need to build my own RPM which will get the work done

Solution:

I was trying to use setuptools (bdist_rpm option) to create my RPM when I hit this blip ;)
Couldn't find any python_sitelib macro in there and I don't want to hard code my python version

Any solutions to this ?

Also if I can use spec file and rpmbuild method ? and someone can help me with that ?

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

python_sitelib is defined in rpm itself (on my Fedora23 it is /usr/lib/rpm/macros).

Here is guidelines how to write python spec:
  https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Python

Command pyp2rpm is also good start.

Comment: Thanks for that info. In the spec file, for my case there is no prep, build involved. So is it ok to skip %prep and %build sections ?  The dumping of module in python_sitelib would go in the %install section ?

Comment: %prep must be present, but it can be empty. Yes in %install you can do something like cp -a foo.py %{buildroot}%{python_sitelib}/

Comment: Thanks. I stumbled upon a blog which is doing almost exactly what I require :) https://www.suse.com/communities/blog/building-simple-rpms-arbitary-files/